# Is there a way to avoid the taskbar getting focus when running a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

I am building a small program I want to hover over the other programs, and I use `TopMost` to handle this quite well.

Now my issue is that once I work in my tool, it also brings the Windows Taskbar forward, whereas I would like not to pull it to the top.

Is there a way to address this?

An acceptable workaround would be to "restore focus" on previous active program, is there an easy way to do this? (like Alt + Tab)

Comment: That's never going to work "properly", just create another top most app for instance. Look up alternative windows shell, that way you'll be working with the OS instead of fighting it all the time.

Comment: I do not follow this answer. I have another full screen application running which takes up all the screen, while I have my timer tool on top. So when I click it to record the timings. My best "workaround" I found so far is once I click for the timing to minimize and resize my program ... thereby releasing focus.

Comment: Wasn't an answer. Topmost isa  window setting if one of the other apps you are hovering over also has a topmost window and does something to cause a repaint, it will gain top most position on top of your app.

Comment: Thanks Tony, helps me understand the issue, and that I need another way to address this. I need to switch focus back on the previous window that is not topmost (even if my tool will still be rendered above thanks to topmost) So its hoover option of fullscreen in front of the windows start menu takes effect. understanding the problem is half the battle :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting the [`ShowInTaskbar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx) property for your form to False? That'll cause your form to not show up in the Windows taskbar.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately it still pulls the taskbar forward.

Answer (score 0):

For the 'restore focus' part of your question, you can use the form.activate method easily enough.

Comment: The program I am monitoring the timings on are another external that I want to switch back to. How would I figure out which program that is. I tried using Alt + Tab but that is quite slow.